# cmake target behavior depends on in-source vs out-of-source invocation

Tags: cmake

In my project, I have a large number of test executables that I only want to build when requested, i.e., "make tests" should create them where "make" without args doesn't.

In my toplevel CMakeLists.txt, I have

```
add_custom_target(tests)
```

And in my subdirectory CMakeLists.txt, I have

```
set (TEST_APP_LIST foo bar)
foreach (TEST_APP ${TEST_APP_LIST})
    add_executable(${TEST_APP} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL ${TEST_APP}.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(${TEST_APP} ${MY_LIBS})
    add_dependencies(tests ${TEST_APP})
endforeach(TEST_APP)
```

Here's the kicker: this works fine when I am doing an out-of-source build, but if I do an in-source build, the tests target is built even when I don't specify it to make. I'd like the tests target to be explicitly requested in either case.

It's tempting to say "well, just don't do in-source builds because they're evil" and that's fair, but at the moment, I need to support both methods for a while.

This is using cmake version 2.6.